# Pickling dictionary data then loading it doesn't work

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, pickle

I am making a client list and I am using a dictionary and pickle to save and store the clients name and age. Unfortunately my save function overwrites any existing users and then my `__init__` function doesn't display the pickled data in the dictionary just the ones I have typed in myself. Also the `add` function doesn't display the label with the client name on it. Can you please help with the pickle problems because I need an answer fast!

Thanks in advance!

```
from Tkinter import *
import pickle


root=Tk()
dic={}
class Launch(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.withdraw()
        root=Toplevel(root)
        root.title("Choose Client")
        self.row=3
        for key in dic:
            Label(root, text=key).grid(row=row, column=0)
            self.row+=1
        l3=Label(root, text="Client Name")
        l3.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.e1=Entry(root)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        l4=Label(root, text="Client age")
        l4.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.e2=Entry(root)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        b3=Button(root, text="Create client", command=self.add)
        b3.grid(row=2)

    def add(self):
        client=self.e1.get()
        age=self.e2.get()
        dic[client]=age
        Label(root, text="%s" % (client)).grid(row=self.row)
        with open("data", "w") as f:
            pickle.dump(dic, f)


    def load(self):
        dic=pickle.load(open("data", "rb"))


app=Launch(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Without reading on, everything you pickled has to be hashable...Are they?

Comment: `load` method is not used at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `load` method is not used at all. The following is modified code to use the `load`.

```
from Tkinter import *
import pickle


root=Tk()
dic={}

class Launch(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.load()  # <-- load
        root.title("Choose Client")
        self.row = 3
        for key in dic:
            Label(root, text=key).grid(row=self.row, column=0)
            self.row += 1
        l3=Label(root, text="Client Name")
        l3.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.e1=Entry(root)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        l4=Label(root, text="Client age")
        l4.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.e2=Entry(root)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        b3=Button(root, text="Create client", command=self.add)
        b3.grid(row=2)

    def add(self):
        client=self.e1.get()
        age=self.e2.get()
        dic[client]=age
        Label(root, text=client).grid(row=self.row)
        self.row += 1  # <--- increase row count
        with open("data", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(dic, f)

    def load(self):
        # should be declared, otherwise, will create local variable
        global dic
        try:
            dic = pickle.load(open("data", "rb"))
        except IOError:  # if file does not exist.
            pass


app = Launch(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Following is another version that use instance variable instead of global variable:

```
from Tkinter import *
import pickle

class Launch(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.load()  # <-- load
        root.title("Choose Client")
        self.row = 3
        for key in self.dic:
            Label(root, text=key).grid(row=self.row, column=0)
            self.row += 1
        l3 = Label(root, text="Client Name")
        l3.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.e1 = Entry(root)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        l4 = Label(root, text="Client age")
        l4.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.e2 = Entry(root)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        b3 = Button(root, text="Create client", command=self.add)
        b3.grid(row=2)

    def add(self):
        client = self.e1.get()
        age = self.e2.get()
        self.dic[client] = age
        Label(root, text=client).grid(row=self.row)
        self.row += 1  # <--- increase row count
        with open("data", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(self.dic, f)

    def load(self):
        try:
            self.dic = pickle.load(open("data", "rb"))
        except IOError:
            self.dic = {}


root = Tk()
app = Launch(root)
root.mainloop()
```